# Why does my scrollbar scroll automatically in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, scrollbar

I am using Windows XP SP3, and facing problem with scroll bar(in windows as well as in browser..). the scroll bar is running on it's own, up and down. I have Formated and reinstalled the Windows OS and also scanned with Antivirus but the problem is still there... is it a Virus or a worm attack?? can it be solved?? So please help.

Comment: What mouse do you use,is it wheel mouse ?

Comment: Yes Wheel mouse, old Scroll mouse with rolling ball and not the laser mouse.

Comment: have you tried any other wheel mouse ?

Comment: no I haven't.. i am using the Logitech Scroll mouse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no,change the mouse because,it is most probably wheel mouse who is culprit, because the sensors of your wheel mouse's scrolling are out of order.

Comment: but when i use browser, and when the scroll bar appears(like in case of Google search, or Youtube..) the scroll bar run's on it's own.. going up and down... with out any event by mouse.. might be a case of Virus(Wild guess ) i think.. I will Try as you said and Let You know...

Comment: yeah! the Mouse was out of order.. need to change... thank you @Mr-Right

Answer (score 1):

As you did a reinstall...

It must be your mouse or the hardware in the computer, to identify which one disconnect the mouse.

- If it still occurs, it is the hardware in your computer, you might need a new mainboard.

  You can try to disconnect other hardware to see if those might be causing it.
- If it is gone, it is your mouse. You can try inspecting the sensors or just buy a new mouse.

Although unlikely, I would recommend checking your keyboard too...

Comment: it was the problem of Mouse, i checked it in my office PC, giving the same problem there too... need to change the Mouse...or repair.., and hey thanks @TomWij your answer was also correct..but can only tik on one..

Comment: No problem, it is wise to give the reputation to a new user... He came first with the right answer anyway. ;-)

Comment: yeah! that's right..